# Filter form with combobox using macro - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, macros

I have created a multiple items form in MS Access 2013 that takes data from a query. I have created filters using macros but the problem is that they only work if in the combobox the rowsource is just text and not the content of a table. In my case that's not practical cause I have dozens of entries and I can't just use text values in it.

So far I have this in the macro to create filter:

```
"=[project number]='" & [Forms]![MyForm]![comboboxProject] & "'"
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know if it's because I have a multiple items form, instead of a simple one. By the way project number is a column of my data and is just text.

After hours of debugging I found that my combobox has two columns, a hidden one with the id of the project and a visible one with the project number. I tried using [comboboxProject].Column(1) but it says that function Column is not defined. So I need to find a way to get only one column as text from my combobox and the problem would be solved.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a macro, instead of **Set Filter** I used **Apply Filter**.
Apart from that, the rest of the code was as simple as this:

```
[project number]=[Forms]![MyForm]![comboboxProject]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Me.Filter = "[project number]='" & [Forms]![MyForm]![comboboxProject] & "'" 
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. However, It still doens't work. It's like it's not filtering, since it returns all the contents of the table.

Comment: Do I write that in the macro? In the Set Filter macro category it has "Filter Name", "Where condition" and "Control Name". Sorry for such questions but I'm really new to this.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. I don't do macros.